# Como retornar el objeto con mayor valor en un array

Tags: javascript, array, objeto

Necesito ayuda con el ultimo ejercicio, no se que mas hacer.

getUltimoCertificado() {
// Escribe una función que retorne el ultimo certificado de un profesor (anio mas alto)

```
      // ej, si la persona tuviera estos certificados:
      // {
      //   certificados: [{
      //     nombre: 'Ingenieria',
      //     anio: 2004,
      //     entidad: 'UNT',
      //   }, {
      //     nombre: 'Master en Datos',
      //     anio: 2012,
      //     entidad: 'UBA'
      //   }]
      // }
      // persona.getUltimoCertificado() // retorna { nombre: 'Master en Datos', anio: 2012', entidad: 'UBA'};
```

Comment: Sería de utilidad que proporciones el código que has escrito que no te funciona para poder ayudarte. Exitos

Comment: Pon lo que has intentado, el código que has escrito, así es mas fácil comprender lo que quieres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obtener el último certificado obtenido con estos datos es posible hacerlo con una simple combinación entre `map` y `filter`.

Primero obtendremos el máximo de los años de cada objeto usando `Math.max()` y `.map()` y luego filtraremos el array original obteniendo todos los cursos que se hayan realizado en el año más alto, es decir el último.

Este método devolverá un array con los objetos que se hayan realizado en un mismo año, ya sea uno, dos o más. Por tanto para ver realmente el último de ellos bastará con acceder a la última posición de este array resultante.

Te adjunto un ejemplo:

```js
const certs = [{
    nombre: 'Ingenieria',
    anio: 2004,
    entidad: 'UNT',
}, {
    nombre: 'Master en Datos',
    anio: 2012,
    entidad: 'UBA'
}, {
    nombre: 'Master en Desarrollo de Software',
    anio: 2012,
    entidad: 'AAW'
}];

const lastOfYears = Math.max(...certs.map(it => it.anio));
const lastCerts = certs.filter(cert => cert.anio === lastOfYears); // array of certs in 2012
const lastCertificateObtained = lastCerts[lastCerts.length - 1];

console.log('Last certificate obtained: ', lastCertificateObtained);
```

Comment: Hola, me sirvio muchas gracias, lo unico que no entendi bien fue esta parte: const lastCertificateObtained = lastCerts[lastCerts.length - 1];

Comment: al hacer `lastCerts[ lastCerts.length - 1 ]` estas accediendo a la posicion de la `longitud` del array menos uno, es decir la ultima posición del array.
Como tienes un array con los certificados obtenidos en un año concreto, pueden ser varios, por lo que accediendo a la ultima posición nos aseguramos de que estamos recibiendo el más último de ellos.

Answer (score 0):

```
getUltimoCertificado() {
  // Escribe una función que retorne el ultimo certificado de un profesor (anio mas alto)
  // ej, si la persona tuviera estos certificados:
  // {
  //   certificados: [{
  //     nombre: 'Ingenieria',
  //     anio: 2004,
  //     entidad: 'UNT',
  //   }, {
  //     nombre: 'Master en Datos',
  //     anio: 2012,
  //     entidad: 'UBA'
  //   }]
  // }
  // persona.getUltimoCertificado() // retorna { nombre: 'Master en Datos', anio: 2012', entidad: 'UBA'};
  var newObjeto ={};
  for(var i = 0; i < this.certificados.length; i++){
    if(this.certificados[i].anio > this.certificados[i].anio) return this.certificados[i];
    newObjeto = this.certificados[i];
  }
  return newObjeto;
  
}
```

Comment: puede que para ti sea bastante obvio lo que hace el codigo mostrado, pero para los demas no. Porfavor agrega detalles de como funciona y explica tu respuesta.